# How do I connect to my wireless router settings on Linux?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection

My network is as follows:

Internet Provider's DSL modem connected to
Internet Provider's router connected to
My Buffalo Wireless router connected to
My Toshiba Laptop via WEP network

My Toshiba Laptop is running LMDE Linux Mint Debian Edition Service Pack 3 i686 kernel

I have experience using various routers and their configuration settings but for some reason I can not access my wireless router.

In my cromium browser I tried the following ip addresses:
Standard Usual IPs : 192.168.1.1, 192.168.0.1  (connection hangs and goes no where)
On the back of my router: 192.168.11.1, 192.168.11.100 (connection hangs and goes nowhere )
In some tcpip info: 192.168.24.1 (unable to connect error message)

If someone could give me some terminal commands that will help me find my wireless router address or some trouble shooting ideas, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Good grief - WEP? That's been known to be trivially crackable for YEARS. You're kidding yourself if you are "securing" a network with WEP. Use WPA2 if you'd like some hope of protection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was finally able to connect.
I needed to set the switch on the back from AUTO to ROUTER mode.
Then I was able to enter the router settings with 198.186.11.1:80
And the default user name is root with a blank password.

My suggestion to people with this problem in the future is check all the switches on your device and the different modes etc.